# Cant start browser - Beaker, Falkon, Colibri

Tags: fstab, browser

Cannot start browsers Beaker, Falkon, Colibri with one of users. Others users work OK.

The error I get is:

```
$ beaker-browser
system_key.go:129: cannot determine nfs usage in generateSystemKey: cannot parse /etc/fstab: expected between 3 and 6 fields, found 7
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and here is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

# READ
# Ubuntu enables periodic TRIM by default no need discard option
# No options means = rw,relatime 
# Ubuntu defaults = rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async. Later options chanve defaults 
# relatime - updates file access info once a day (by default) or on file change. noatime - dont update
# nosuid - other users cant execute not their files

# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=824d5fbe-3233-416b-5e23-211458762912 /               btrfs   defaults,subvol=@ 0       1

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=0BG8-0215  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1

# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID= 824d5fbe-3233-416b-5e23-211458762912 /home           btrfs   defaults,subvol=@home 0       2
UUID= 824d5fbe-3233-416b-5e23-211458762912 /media/Disk           btrfs   defaults,subvol=@Disk  umask=0000 0       2

# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=c3v5f6c4-dy53-33b5-ag6n-fnc513975b9g none            swap    sw              0       0


# /dev/sda5 /media/FAT32-19GB vfat user 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you get says:

> ```
> cannot parse /etc/fstab: expected between 3 and 6 fields, found 7
> ```

The 6 fields that the error mentions are described in the 7th line of your `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
```

The fields are separated using whitespace and the error means that somewhere you have added additional whitespace, so now the number of fields is 7.

By inspecting your `/etc/fstab`, we can see that you have added a space right after `UUID=` at the lines mounting your `/home` and `/media/Disk` (lines 23-24).

Just remove the space after `UUID=` so that the lines become:

```
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=824d5fbe-3233-416b-5e23-211458762912 /home           btrfs   defaults,subvol=@home 0       2
UUID=824d5fbe-3233-416b-5e23-211458762912 /media/Disk           btrfs   defaults,subvol=@Disk  umask=0000 0       2
```

After that reboot your computer.